# How to schedule running Moodle cron using windows scheduler and the cron URL?

Tags: linux, windows, cron, task, scheduler

I have Moodle 2.5 on a linux server, i dont know anything about scheduling cron.

I can execute the cron from a webpage by going to the URL like this http://moodle2.domainaname.org/admin/cron.php

I would like to schedule this cron to run on the Linux server (by calling this web address) from a windows server / windows scheduler .. Is this possible?  if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to set cron job for it. Go through following link. 
I hope it will be useful for you.

> http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/